# Where to store scripts in a Python project?

Tags: python, package, repository, structure

I'm working on a machine learning python project. As a part of this project I have two components: (1) the library itself, with the model definitions, data processing functions, etc., and (2) a set of scripts that execute and train models, generate data, etc. These scripts are using the functionalities implemented in the library. The library component is where functionalities are defined and the scripts component is where functionalities are executed.

My question is how to store this kind of script in my repository. I have two options:

1. **Use python entry points**: The first option is to have all these scripts as part of the library and install them using python entry points.

```
project
│
└───library
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   └───subfolder1
│   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │   file1.py
│   │   │   file2.py
│   │   │   ...
│   └───scripts
│       │   __init__.py
│       │   script1.py
│       │   script2.py
│       │   ...
│
│ setup.py
│ setup.cfg
```

where `setup.cfg` installs the scripts like

```
[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    execute-script1 = library.scripts.script1:main
    execute-script2 = library.scripts.script2:main
```

And the scripts, after installing the package, are executed from the command line like `execute-script1 --arg1 ...`.

2. **Script folder**: the second option is to have a folder of scripts outside the library with all the scripts defined there. This is, something like

```
project
│
└───library
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   └───subfolder1
│       │   file1.py
│       │   file2.py
│       │   ...
│   
│ setup.py
│
└───scripts
    │   script1.py
    │   script2.
```

where `setup.py` installs only the modules in `library`. And the scripts look like

```py
def parse_args():
    ...

def main():
    args = parse_args()
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And the scripts are executed from the command line like `python scripts/scrip1.py --arg1 ...`

Which is the recommended way to store these scripts? I've been looking at several python projects but I couldn't find a standard way.